# Library for creating an augmented reality app on dynamic markers

Tags: android, ios, game-development, artificial-intelligence, augmented-reality

I'm trying to build an application similar to [Wanna Kicks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UmsPqRQXxk). I'm looking for a recommendation for AR library that will enable me to display 3D objects on top of human legs.

I guess that the library I'm looking for will give me the ability to train the application on a predefined images/modules of the human leg, allow me to detect the angle/rotation & position of the leg and place the 3D object of top of the leg image.

I worked before with SDKs like Vuforia, ARCore & ARKit, and they doesn't provide the ability to track the kind of trackers I'm talking about. They can detect markers of static 2d and 3d objects with static shapes and features.

I'm also aware that I mostly won't find a library that will satisfy all the requirements I'm looking to fulfill. I'm also looking for options that will do the dirty work for me(training, detection), but in the same time they support that I can add the other missing requirements for it(detecting position & rotation).

What are my options for an augmented reality library or non-Augmented reality library but still can do the job?

I'm looking for a library which runs on Android, ios or both of them.